# Cosine Similarity [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-mining, cosine-similarity

With the following code of my function which compute the cosine similarity of a query with a data:

```
def rank_retrieve(self, query):
        """
        Given a query (a list of words), return a rank-ordered list of
        documents and score for the query.
        self.docs : list of documents
        self.docs[i] : list of words in doc number i -> [word1,word2,...,wordN]
        self.boolean_retrieve(query) : giving a list of words this return the index of
        documents wich contains all of these words.
        self.tfidf(word,documentIndex) : returns the value tfidf of a word in a document
        self.get_posting(word): returns a list of document index where that word appears
        """
    scores = [0.0 for xx in range(len(self.docs))]

    # Apply Cosine Similarity
    for i in self.boolean_retrieve(query):
        normDoc = 0.0
        normQuery = 0.0
        dt = 0.0
        qtdt = 0.0
        for word in query:
            dt = self.get_tfidf(word,i)
            normDoc+= math.pow(dt,2)

            qt = 1.0 + ( math.log10( len(query) ) )
            normQuery+=math.pow(qt,2)

            qtdt += dt * qt
        scores[i] = qtdt / ( math.sqrt(normDoc) )

    return scores
```

I just have the next teory: 
[image]

So, can you help me with my code? I return wrong values and I don't know why.
Thanks.

Result of doc 56 score:

```
Cosine Similarity Test
doc 56, query :   ['separ', 'of', 'church', 'and', 'state']

Separ: 
QTDT:  0.105587429399 
DT 0.0621479067488 
QT 1.69897000434 
NormDoc:  0.00386236231326  normQuery 2.88649907563

Of:
QTDT:  0.105587429399 
DT 0.0 
QT 1.69897000434 
NormDoc:  0.00386236231326  normQuery 5.77299815127

Church :
QTDT:  0.653857934128 
DT 0.322707583613 
QT 1.69897000434 
NormDoc:  0.108002546834  normQuery 8.6594972269

And:
QTDT:  0.653857934128 
DT 0.0 
QT 1.69897000434 
NormDoc:  0.108002546834  normQuery 11.5459963025

State:
QTDT:  0.674927180008 
DT 0.0124011876763 
QT 1.69897000434 
NormDoc:  0.10815633629  normQuery 14.4324953782

Scores of 56 must be 0.010676611271744128 found : 2.05225316563
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the red terms, or not? Did the reference solution include them, or not?

They are not necessary with respect to obtaining the same *ranking* but they should have an effect on the *numerical* values, if I'm not mistaken.

Also, your definition of cosine similarity seems to be nonstandard, due to the use of these `1+log` terms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Comment: The reference solution uses ltc.lnn weighting for computing cosine scores, that is, ltc for the document and lnn for the query, with the red part for the dt and without idf for the qt ( tfidf for dt and only 1+log(tf) for the query). I think that i'm doing it correctly but I don't obtain the result :/

Comment: `len(query)` at least is not N/df; which would make your `qt` terms incorrect. But note that we cannot really check your code, as most is missing (e.g. `get_tfidf`).

Answer (score 0):

```
def calctfidfvec(tfvec, withidf):
    tfidfvec = {}
    veclen = 0.0

    for token in tfvec:
        if withidf:
            tfidf = (1+log10(tfvec[token])) * getidf(token)
        else:
            tfidf = (1+log10(tfvec[token]))
        tfidfvec[token] = tfidf 
        veclen += pow(tfidf,2)

    if veclen > 0:
        for token in tfvec: 
            tfidfvec[token] /= sqrt(veclen)

    return tfidfvec

def cosinesim(vec1, vec2):
    commonterms = set(vec1).intersection(vec2)
    sim = 0.0
    for token in commonterms:
        sim += vec1[token]*vec2[token]

    return sim
```

Comment: Please add some explanation also?